# DataTime don't publish more that days in database

Tags: php

I would like to save dates on the database, but when I save them, the hours, minutes, and seconds are not saved.
I use this function to save the date.

```
public function saveEdit() {
    $author = $this->authentication->getUser();
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $post = $this->postTable->findById($_GET['id']);

        if ($post['authorid'] != $author['id']) {
            return;
        }
    }

    $post = $_POST['post'];
    $post['postdate'] = new \DateTime();
    $post['authorid'] = $author['id'];

    $this->postTable->save($post);
    
    header('location: /post/list'); 
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the schame for this table please. Probably the column is defined as DATE and not DATETIME

Comment: `$this->postTable->save($post)` receives a `DateTime` object with all the goodies. Whatever's discarding time happens later.

Comment: Solved, i've noted that i do a forcing for pass only the date parameters and not the time parameters